# Transaction multiple EV/LTM EBITDA

Tags: valuation

Envestnet acquired Yodlee in 2015. I need for this transaction the multiple EV (enterprise value) over last twelve months EBITDA. Can anybody help me with this?
In the respective investor relations website they refer only to an amount of $590 million for the enterprise value at the announcement date, however no other info beside that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The multiple is EV/EBITDA.

1) use income statement and cash flow statement of the respective firm to calculate the EBITDA for the last twelve months - EBITDA is supposed to be a proxy for cash flow

2) divide the given Enterprise Value by your calculated EBITDA

3) you receive the EV/EBITDA multiple which tells you that firm x is (in theory) worth for example 7.1 times it's EBITDA with regard to enterprise value.